# Dynamics CRM 2011 How are revised Quotes linked together?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In CRM 2011 I was trying to import some Quotes when I realized that I couldn't set the Revision Number.  As a last resort I considered updating the tables directly since the installation is On Premise, but I realized that there is a part of process that I do not understand.  That part is how are revised Quotes linked to the original?

I know that when you revise a Quote it creates a copy of that Quote and then increments the Revision Number, but I don't see any type of pointer that says which Quote its revising.  To give you an example.  Opportunities can have multiple Quotes.  Lets pretend this one has Quote A and Quote B.  Quote A is at Revision Number 5 and Quote B is at Revision Number 7.  I query all the Quotes for my Opportunity and choose one with a Revision Number of 3.  How do I know if its from Quote A or Quote B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a direct relationship between the revised quotes and the current draft/active quote (but you can create one and keep updated using a plugin).

The only way to find the related quotes is the `Quote ID` (`quotenumber` field), it will not change between the revisions.

Comment: That was the missing piece.  They hadn't listed QuoteNumber as a field to be migrated so I had overlooked it.  I am wondering now though.  If I import two quotes with the same quote number, will it automatically increment the Revision Number of the second one for me?

Comment: depends what are you using for the import, but if I remember correctly, the combination of quotenumber and revision is considered as a primary key and CRM will throw you an exception if you try to create a quote with an existing quotenumber-revision combination

Comment: Well Revision Number is read only so it can't be set.  I'm trying to import Quotes and I thought that by setting the Quote Number to an existing Quote Number it would increment the Revision Number for me.  As it turns out it doesn't, it actually overwrites the Quote Number and assigns a whole new one.

I can use the ReviseQuoteRequest but the issue I have is that I need to use the same Guids when I am importing.  You can do this when you create a new Quote but I don't see that I can when I revise a Quote.

Comment: Revised Quotes are meant to be created using the ReviseQuoteRequest instead of trying to manually set the link between the quotes.  You are correct however QuoteNumber is the field that ties the revisions together.  If you try to create a quote yourself and manually set the Quote Number to an existing one CRM will just change the quote number to something different.